# wrong number or types of arguments in call to '<' in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here I'm creating a procedure where the condition is hire date should be less than sysdate. It is showing me an error. How to solve this error?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employees (hire_date IN NUMBER) IS   
BEGIN
  IF hire_date < SYSDATE THEN
    INSERT INTO emp (emp_id,
                     emp_name,
                     email,
                     phone_number,
                     hire_date,
                     job_id,
                     sal)
     VALUES (empinc.NEXTVAL,
             'ravi',
             'ravi@gmail.com',
             '6578940983456',
             '08/09/2021',
             'JUN_TECH',
             60000);
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('failed');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Comment: *... it is showing me error*, but for some reason you do not show it us. Why? Should we guess? And what's the point?

Comment: `hire_date IN number` - is hire_date a number? Then in your insert, it's `'08/09/2021'` - is hire_date a string?

Comment: On a side note: Be aware of Oracle's misnomer; `SYSDATE` is not "today" as one would expect, but "now" (date and time). If you want "today", use `TRUNC(SYSDATE)'`.

Comment: Talking of misnomers: I'd be very surprised to find a procedure in a database that is called employees, for the name doesn't give the slightest hint as to what that procedure might do.

Answer (score 1):

`sysdate` is a function that returns `date` datatype value. You can't compare it to a number (which is `hire_date` parameter's datatype).

It should be

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employees (hire_date IN DATE)
IS                                                  ----
BEGIN                                               this
   IF hire_date < SYSDATE
```

or (which would be wrong, though) something like this (which depends on  format you used for `hire_date`; I chose `yyyymmdd`):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE employees (hire_date IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
   IF hire_date < to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'yyyymmdd'))    --> this
```